# How can I delete all .mp3 files in the current linux directory that are older than 365 days?

Tags: files, filesystem, filemanager

How can I delete all .mp3 files in the current linux directory that are older than 365 days?

I am looking for a shell command I can use to do this. There are other files in this directory that I don't want to be deleted.

Thank you.

Comment: It is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Read `man find` and do something like this (remove `echo` when you like the results):

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.mp3' -mtime +365 -print0 |\
  xargs -0 -r echo rm`